# Select não duplicar informaçao

Tags: php, html

Eu tenho um SELECT e o que eu quero é que se existir duas OPTION com o mesmo valor ele só mostre uma.

Como mostra no exemplo a baixo tenho 2 Options com Micosoft e eu quero apenas que ele me mostre uma so Option com Microsoft visto que eu estou a listar essa informaçao de uma base de dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<select class="form-control" id="inserir_fabricante2">
    <option value="" ></option>
        <?php
            $query_d = "SELECT * FROM reparacao ORDER BY fabricante ASC";
            $pv_d = (mysql_query($query_d));
                 while ($row_d = mysql_fetch_array($pv_d)){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_d['fabricante']; ?>" ><?php echo  $row_d['fabricante']; ?></option>
                  <?php }   ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso, você pode utilizar o SELECT DISTINCT, por exemplo:

```
<select class="form-control" id="inserir_fabricante2">
<option value="" ></option>
    <?php
        $query_d = "SELECT DISTINCT fabricante FROM reparacao ORDER BY fabricante ASC";
        $pv_d = (mysql_query($query_d));
             while ($row_d = mysql_fetch_array($pv_d)){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row_d['fabricante']; ?>" ><?php 
        echo  $row_d['fabricante']; ?></option>
              <?php }   ?>
</select>
```

Para saber mais  [sobre o SELECT DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda !!

Comment: eita, erro meu kkkkkkkk

Comment: Não Importa voce orientou minha mente para a resposta ahah Obrigado!!